# Need to split states per region in query

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a query (picture will be included) that need to sort information by Region and then State for lifetime and monthly values.  I have everything working correctly (and have had for several months) except one hiccup.  The state of Georgia is in two regions, and the information for it on the monthly side doubles.

EDIT:  Apparently I can't post screenshots.  Let me know how I can get a screenshot to you for understanding purposes.

The query is made up of two separate queries, because that is the only way I can get my information to be accurate.  In the "Lifetime" query, all information is correct.  In the "Monthly" query, all information is correct.  When I combine the queries, that is when GA doubles information.  I can't think of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you could post the query, some sample data, the output that you get and the output that you expect it will be much easier to help you :) You can post images using this markup: `![a busy cat](http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)`. Of course you need to have your image on-line somewhere but that shoudn;t be a problem nowadays.

Comment: Just a guess, but when you "combine" the two queries are you performing a JOIN between the two on [State] alone? If so, then 'GA' will get duplicated because of the multiple [Region] values. Doing a JOIN on [State] *and* [Region] would probably fix that.

Comment: Thanks Gord!  Amazing how I missed something that simple.  You have fixed my issue, and I am so grateful for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the two queries by performing a JOIN between them on [State] alone will cause 'GA' to be duplicated because of the multiple [Region] values. You'll need to perform a JOIN on [State] *and* [Region] to fix that.